# Indentation error in VS Code for Python script

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run the following script in VS Code, however I keep getting an indentation error, which is kinda self-explanatory, but I haven't been able to find the error? Is there a way auto-formatting in VS Code?

```
import logging
import uuid
import json

import azure.functions as func


def main(msg: func.QueueMessage, message: func.Out[func.Document]) -> None:

    logging.info('Python queue trigger function processed a queue item: %s', msg_body)
    data = json.dumps({
        'id': msg.id,
        'body': msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'),
        'expiration_time': (msg.expiration_time.isoformat()
                            if msg.expiration_time else None),
        'insertion_time': (msg.insertion_time.isoformat()
                           if msg.insertion_time else None),
        'time_next_visible': (msg.time_next_visible.isoformat()
                             if msg.time_next_visible else None),
        'pop_receipt': msg.pop_receipt,
        'dequeue_count': msg.dequeue_count
    })
    message.set(func.Document.from_json(json.dumps(data)))
```

My error message when I run the script:

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\artem\Desktop\function\inspariqueuestore\__init__.py"
  File "c:\Users\artem\Desktop\function\inspariqueuestore\__init__.py", line 12
    data = json.dumps({
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.093 seconds
```

**UPDATE**

I mixed tabs and spaces apparently. Issue resolved.

Comment: Did you mix tabs and spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any indentation errors in your file.

Yes, you can try to format your file using VS Code. 
There is a shortcut named `editor.action.formatDocument`. 
You can find the exact keys for your setup in settings.

In my case it is `shift + option (alt) + F`

Comment: I tried using autopep8 for formatting, which didn't change the indentation. When I try to debug the function, it still fails du to unexpected indentation.

Comment: @Artem thank you. The code you pasted to the SO seems OK.
Can you try to remove the indentation before the `data` variable and then put it back?

Maybe you mixed tabs and spaces?

Comment: I mixed tabs and spaces - just reformatted the entire thing with search and replace. Thanks for your help